# Expanding a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have allocated an array as follows.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int first_dim = 3;
    const int second_dim = 2;

    // Allocate array and populate with dummy data
    int** myArray = new int*[first_dim];
    for (int i = 0; i < first_dim; i++) {
        myArray[i] = new int[second_dim];
        for (int j = 0; j < second_dim; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = i*second_dim + j;
            std::cout << "[i = " << i << ", j = " << j << "] Value: " << myArray[i][j] << "\n";
        }
    }

    // De-allocate array
    for (int i = 0; i < first_dim; i++)
        delete[] myArray[i];
    delete[] myArray;
}
```

Let's say I want to add a 4th element to the first dimension, i.e. `myArray[3]`. Is this possible?

I've heard that Vectors are so much more efficient for this purpose, but I hardly know what they are and I've never used them before.

Comment: did you try to use `std::vector`? looks like it might suit your needs better.

Comment: Regardless of vectors (which you should probably use in this case), you should have used delete[] instead of delete in both cases, since you allocated an array.

Comment: Using vectors is not a very difficult task.

Comment: Using a single contiguous buffer for all dimensions might improve cache locality and perform better - worth considering.

Comment: Yes ,your code will be very messy and error prone when you try to dynamically allocate memory yourself.As suggested ,use    std::vector    .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but in a very painful way. What you have to do is allocate new memory which now has your new desired dimensions, in this case 4 and 2, then copy all the contents of your matrix to your new matrix, and then free the memory of the previous matrix... that's painful. Now let's see how the same is done with vectors:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

int main()
{
   vector< vector <int> > matrix;
   matrix.resize(3);
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
      matrix[i].resize(2);

   matrix[0][1] = 4;
   //...

   //now you want to make the first dimension 4? Piece of cake

   matrix.resize(4);
   matrix[3].resize(2);
}
```

HTH

***edit:***
some comments on your original code:

- In C++ ALL_CAP_NAMES usually refer to macros (something you #define). Avoid using them in other contexts
- why do you declare FIRSTDIM and SECONDDIM static? That is absolutely unnecessary. If a local variable is static it means informally that it will be the same variable next time you call the function with kept value. Since you technically can't call main a second sime this is useless. Even if you could do that it would still be useless.
- you should wrire `delete [] array[i];` and `delete [] array;` so the compiler knows that the int* and int** you're trying to delete actually point to an array, not just an int or int* respectively.

Comment: Just a pedantic point: can't you just reallocate `myArray` to size 4 and assign the pointers? You can keep the same sub arrays and just point to them from the reallocated `myArray`, right?

Comment: JoshD: Don't sabotage my tries to scare people away from arrays :) When you tell your children not to do drugs you don't mention that if you smoke pot a couple of times that won't make you a terrorist, though it is true :)

Comment: You can do better than that: `vector<vector<int> > matrix(3, vector<int>(2));` Creates and initializes the matrix in one line.

Comment: @Martin :) I know, I just wanted to keep analogy with what the OP wrote. I think he would have much difficulty understanding vector<vector<int> > matrix(3, vector<int>(2)); And anyway after the resize we would have to resize matrix[3]. Please keep in mind that the OP has no experience with vectors. This example is meant to encourage him to study more. And once he does, he will learn details.

Comment: @Martin I am at least glad you didn't suggest using iterators instead of indexing :)

Comment: Armen I could not understand the last item about deleting array but not a pointer. Is "new int[second_dim]" an array or a pointer? It is a dinamically allocated array. But when you delete it, you write "delete[] myArray[i]". I could not understand what is your remark at this point.

Comment: @Narek. My point was that both `new int` and `new int[10]` return a pointer to int (`int*`). In order to free the memory you should explicitly tell the compiler while deleting how to treat that pointer - as one that points to one int or at one that points to an array,

Comment: @Narek: Sorry in the original OP's code, which he has edited he wrote `delete array[i];` and `delete array;` which is undefined behaviour in C++

Comment: If I declare a vector as a class member, do I have to manually free the memory that was used by the vector in the class destructor?

Comment: No, as if the vector is a member (and not a pointer to the vector which is dynamically allocated later) than during your class destructor work all member destructors are being called, and of course, the verctors detructor is being called too.

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say I want to add a 4th element to the first dimension, i.e. myArray[3]. Is this possible?

Yes, but it's a pain in the neck. It basically boils down to allocating a new array, just as your existing code does (hint: put it in the function and make the sizes arguments to that function) and copying compatible elements over.

**Edit**:  One of the things that `std::vector` does for you is properly de-allocating you memory. In the code you have, failure to allocate one of the arrays along the 2nd dimension will result in a memory leak. A more robust solution would initialize pointers to 0 before performing any allocation. An exception block could then catch the exception and free whatever was partially allocated.

Because this code becomes complex quickly, people resort to allocating a single buffer and addressing using a stride or using a 1D array of 1D arrrays (i.e. `std::vector` of `std::vector`s).